# How can I target a div on my HTML page with Javascript to change the contents of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, targeting

I've got an interesting question. I'm running Squarespace @ [buscadprimero.caminoglobal.org](http://buscadprimero.caminoglobal.org)
and need to target the top-right button on the navigation (Ingresar, which means login) to bring up a Javascript form provided to me via embed code. The code itself works fine when included as a code block in the body of a page, but Squarespace only allows navigation buttons at the top to be hyperlinks. There's nowhere for me to add code to the button itself, being that it is a largely consumer platform and works great for straightforward application until you try to change the way it works.

They make an allowance for custom code via a "code injection" menu that adds whatever code you want to the HTML header of the page, so I've been trying to target this div, which does not have an id but who's class is `external`, with Javascript to replace its contents with an `onclick` listener to bring up this form. Tracking?

Here's my embed code, which like I said is fine:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
   !function(e,t){e._cc={}, e._cc.host="https://www.coachingcloud.com/";var n=function(){var n=t.createElement("script"),c=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.src=e._cc.host+"login.min.js",c.parentNode.insertBefore(n,c)};e.addEventListener?e.addEventListener("load",n,!1):e.attachEvent("onload",n)}(window,document);
// ]]></script>
```

I've been trying `document.getElementsByClassName("external").innerHTML;` but when set to a var that returns `undefined`. New to Javascript but not afraid to learn. I'd like to figure out how to properly target the div, first of all, and then replace its contents (which currently is a link to my 404 page) with a Javascript function that activates on click. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: From clicking the link in your question: `Squarespace trial accounts are not visible to the public. When you are ready to publish your website, upgrading your trial will make your site active to the world.`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("external")[0].innerHTML;`. `getElementsByClassName` returns a list. Use the browser console to debug these things.

Comment: You're right, the site is still in trial mode, but it can easily be accessed by entering the captcha code.

Comment: I've been using a browser console actually, just not exactly sure how to implement what you are suggesting. I'm not sure how to confirm that I'm correctly accessing that content because I don't know how to subsequently replace the content inside that div.

Comment: @Arg0n do you know how to change the contents of the div once it's been accessed? Right now it contains a link to my 404 page, like I said, but it needs to link to a Javascript function that pulls up the code I mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you try `document.querySelector(".external").innerHTML` it works at this time on your website, but `querySelector`return only the first element, so if you page change and you have more than one element with `.external`class, it'll not work.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector (see the compatibility list at the bottom)

Comment: Thanks, that was able to get me to successfully target the div, but now my issue is not being able to successfully replace its contents with what is needed to bring up the login popup. Setting the `.innerHTML` element with anything but a basic string breaks my alert that shows me what the div contains (so I can't verify it), and regardless of what I set it to, the actual ingresar button stays unchanged, and still links to the default 404 page that it's set to. So it seems like my replacing of content isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: Can someone please tell me what all these downvotes are about? I'm just a user trying to get help from the community, and the question was answered successfully. Why am I being penalized for a legitimate question with a correct answer? @Arg0n, do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the great help of @Arg0n, I've now got a working login form that appears in the top-right-most button of my site. Using:

`$(function() { $("#mainNavigation .collection").last().html("<span id='cc-login'>Ingresar</span>"); });`

as the function to replace the contents of the `div` in question, I inserted `<span id='cc-login'>Ingresar</span>` as the call to the provided embed code:

`<![CDATA[ !function(e,t){e._cc={}, e._cc.host="https://www.coachingcloud.com/";var n=function(){var n=t.createElement("script"),c=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.src=e._cc.ho‌​st+"login.min.js",c.parentNode.insertBefore(n,c)};e.addEventListener?e.addEventLi‌​stener("load",n,!1):e.attachEvent("onload",n)}(window,document); // ]]>`

Turns out that a little jQuery was helpful in accessing the desired `div`, and setting its `html` contents was a bit beyond my area of expertise.

Many thanks to the StackOverflow community for helping me learn about targeting page elements with Javascript to procedurally manipulate its contents.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? It is the correct answer. I should know, being that it's my own problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following on your site in Chrome, and have successfully changed the content. The page contained multiple ".collection" elements, so i select only the last one:

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$("#mainNavigation .collection").last().html("<a href='/newlink'>Test</a>");
```

Comment: Glad it seemed to work for you, but I'm still seeing no result when I put that code into my code injection area. I've got it exactly like you just said, and the jQuery is working on my site because I'm using it in another script.

`<script>
$("#mainNavigation .collection").last().html("<a href='http://google.com'>Test</a>");
</script>`

Is it possible Squarespace is overriding that script? It just seems like nothing I try is having any effect.

Comment: Can you try placing it inside `$(function() { //code here });`?

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks. That's working! But now to get my provided javascript embed in there instead of just a new link. Let me try that really quickly and I'll report back.

Comment: Alright, now comes the tricky part. The embed code only activates when attached to a span with the id of "cc-login", so on the page where it's currently working in the body, it looks like this:

`<span id="cc-login">Ingresar</span>`

followed by the original embed code shown at the top

Comment: And what do you want to do?

Comment: The code I've got on my site is now this:

`<script>
$(function() { $("#mainNavigation .collection").last().html("<a href='http://google.com/'>Link</a>"); });
</script>`

Putting the required span in there instead of a link sets everything back to not having an effect, however. Not sure how to get it to accept a span. Is there any way this would work by putting javascript as the target of the link instead of an href?

Comment: I want the contents of the div we're altering to inject the span with the id of "cc-login" since that is what my embedded popup login form looks for to activate. It's not simply a hyperlink.

Comment: Then just alter `<a href='http://google.com/'>Link</a>` to be what you want to inject (`<span id="cc-login">Ingresar</span>`).

Comment: That did it! Thank you for walking me through the process. I'm up and running, my final code looking like this: `<script>
$(function() { $("#mainNavigation .collection").last().html("<span id='cc-login'>Ingresar</span>"); });

// <![CDATA[
   !function(e,t){e._cc={}, e._cc.host="https://www.coachingcloud.com/";var n=function(){var n=t.createElement("script"),c=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.src=e._cc.host+"login.min.js",c.parentNode.insertBefore(n,c)};e.addEventListener?e.addEventListener("load",n,!1):e.attachEvent("onload",n)}(window,document);
// ]]>
</script>`